# Automatically New Pages Created in HTML2PDF

Tags: php, html2pdf

I am using *HTml2pdf* library to convert HTML to PDF.

Below is the code i am using.

**PHP**

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf(); 
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->setTestTdInOnePage(false); 
$html = file_get_contents('index.html'); 
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->output();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bap">
<div class="row">
<div class="par_col">
<div class="column">
  <img src="b.jpg" alt="test">
  <table style="width:99%" class="feetop">

    <tr>
      <td class="t_head">Challan No.</td>
      <td class="lii undl">18584</td> 
      <td class="t_heada">Due Date:</td>
      <td  class="liia undl"></td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="t_head_c">Name</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="lii undl">Hamza Zafeer</td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Program:</td>
      <td class="lii undl de">BS Civil Tech  </td> 
      <td >Roll No.</td>
      <td class="undl"></td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Semester</td>
      <td class="undl"></td> 
      <td>Session</td>
      <td class="undl">2018-2021</td> 

    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:99%" class="fee">
    <tr>
      <th >PARTICULARS</th>
      <th>Rs.</th> 
      <th>Ps.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Registration Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Admission Fee</td>
     <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuition Fee</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laboratory Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Library Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transcript / Degree Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Examination Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Security Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hostel Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transport charges</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fine</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc.</td>
      <td>1000</td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Payable</td>
      <td>1000</td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <div class="btm">
    <div class="fm rss"><strong>Rs. in words :</strong> One thousand only</div>
    <div class="fm bt"> Cashier</div>
  </div>
</div></div>
<div class="par_col">
<div class="column">
  <img src="a.jpg" alt="test">
  <table style="width:99%" class="feetop">

    <tr>
      <td class="t_head">Challan No.</td>
      <td class="lii undl">18584</td> 
      <td class="t_heada">Due Date:</td>
      <td  class="liia undl"></td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="t_head_c">Name</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="lii undl">Hamza Zafeer</td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Program:</td>
      <td class="lii undl de">BS Civil Tech  </td> 
      <td >Roll No.</td>
      <td class="undl"></td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Semester</td>
      <td class="undl"></td> 
      <td>Session</td>
      <td class="undl">2018-2021</td> 

    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:99%" class="fee">
    <tr>
      <th >PARTICULARS</th>
      <th>Rs.</th> 
      <th>Ps.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Registration Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Admission Fee</td>
     <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuition Fee</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laboratory Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Library Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transcript / Degree Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Examination Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Security Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hostel Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transport charges</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fine</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc.</td>
      <td>1000</td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
   <div class="btm">
    <div class="fm rss"><strong>Rs. in words :</strong> One thousand only</div>
    <div class="fm bt"> Cashier</div>
  </div>
</div></div>
<div class="par_col">
<div class="column">
  <img src="s.jpg" alt="test">
  <table style="width:99%" class="feetop">

    <tr>
      <td class="t_head">Challan No.</td>
      <td class="lii undl">18584</td> 
      <td class="t_heada">Due Date:</td>
      <td  class="liia undl"></td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="t_head_c">Name</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="lii undl">Hamza Zafeer</td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Program:</td>
      <td class="lii undl de">BS Civil Tech  </td> 
      <td >Roll No.</td>
      <td class="undl"></td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Semester</td>
      <td class="undl"></td> 
      <td>Session</td>
      <td class="undl">2018-2021</td> 

    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:99%" class="fee">
    <tr>
      <th >PARTICULARS</th>
      <th>Rs.</th> 
      <th>Ps.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Registration Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Admission Fee</td>
     <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuition Fee</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laboratory Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Library Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transcript / Degree Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Examination Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Security Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hostel Fee</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Transport charges</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fine</td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Misc.</td>
      <td>1000</td> 
      <td></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
   <div class="btm">
    <div class="fm rss"><strong>Rs. in words :</strong> One thousand only</div>
    <div class="fm bt"> Cashier</div>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

**OUTPUT of HTML**

[image]

But When i generate PDF, each section converted into a single page, and final PDF consisted on 3 pages.

[image]

**Problem**

It should not generate the 3 pages of PDF.  Anybody can tell me what i am doing wrong, why it is creates 3 pages instead of 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

I think it lacks the space, try to wrap your tables in one more table, like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>%table1HTML%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>%table2HTML%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>%table3HTML%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```